# Asking for user input until it matches the text present in a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have a scenario where I have a list of names of countries. Now, I have to prompt for user input 5 times and if that input matches a particular string in the list, then I have to append that string into a second list. If the value entered does not match with any name in the list, then I have to keep on asking the user until a correct word is typed. My python code is mentioned below.

**Python Code:**

```
a = []
for i in range(5):
    b = str(input("Enter the name: "))

    if(b == 'USA' or b == 'UK'):
        a.append(b)

    else:
        for name in a:

            if(b == name):
                c.append(name)


print(c)
```

**Problem:**
I am not able to compare the user input with the strings present in the list.

Can someone please help me in implementing the above-mentioned logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if your input provided country exists in a list you can do the following:

```
country = input("Enter the name of a country: ")
if country in country_names:
   # logic if exists
else:
   # logic is not exists
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if name not in country_name:
    country_list.append(name)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.